# I'm using React to retrieve data from Firebase, but the userItem is not defined in my render function why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I can see the data in console.log, but I couldn't pass it to render function with authenticated user information from firebase.
Can anyone help please.
I've tried many ways, when I use this.setState({..}) and use this.state.userItem in the return, but it tells me that the setState function is not defined. I've been stuck on this for two days. and this.state.userItem is not defined either and goes to code error.

`class AccInfo extends React.Component {
      state = {
        userItem: null
      }

```
  componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        var db = firebase.firestore()
        db.collection('user').doc(user.uid)
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                const userItem = snapshot.data()
                console.log(userItem.name)
                this.setState({userItem: userItem})
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

      } else {

      }})
  }
  render() {
    return( <div>
              <p>{userItem.name}</p>//this is where I mess up
            </div>
          )
    }
  }
export default AccInfo;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [Arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (=>) function, it will preserve the `this` context.
When using the Native function, it creates its own `this`, so when you do, `this.setState({userItem: userItem})`, the `state` of your component isn't updated.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {..// rest of the code..}
```